# What is ament_cmake job?

Tags: ros, ros2, package.xml, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. created a `rclcpp` package:
2. removed `<depend>ament_cmake</depend>` from `package.xml`
3. removed `find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)` from `CMakeLists.txt`

However, the package still builds fine.
The question is what does `ament_cmake` do in the `CMakeList.txt` exaclty? I thought it makes the `colcon` builds but I am able to build without it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349571/what-is-ament_cmake-job?/) by [aby](https://answers.ros.org/users/52503/aby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the main role of `ament_cmake` is to provide CMake macros that will make your job easier when developing multiple packages that depend on each other. None of it is *required* to build a CMake based ROS package.

An example of such macro is `ament_target_dependencies`, it condenses the following cmake logic into a single call:

- target_compile_definitions()
- target_include_directories()
- target_link_libraries()
- setting link flags on the target

Another (the most?) important macro it provides is `ament_package`.
This is what will handle the registration of your package in the ament index, generate the CMake config files for the project to be find_package'able, install the extra CMake config files you provide, install the package.xml of your package etc

You can find some information about `ament_cmake` in the section "Build type: ament_cmake" of https://design.ros2.org/articles/ament.html

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aby](https://answers.ros.org/users/52503/aby/) on 2020-04-20**:
Thank you for your quick reply.
Since we still at it, I have another question about ament. I know that `ament_python` is for building packages using python's `setup.py` and (for now) users can not mix `ament_cmake` with `ament_python` in the same package.

The question is what does `ament_cmake_python` do? and an explanation with a use-case/example would make me happy.

Sorry, there is just some lack of information/use-cases out there about some of ament functions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-20**:
@aby: please do not post follow-up questions in comments under already accepted answers. Post a new question.

Then refer to your old question in your new question.

**Comment by [aby](https://answers.ros.org/users/52503/aby/) on 2020-04-20**:
Sorry, I am new here. I will post a new question. Thanks

**Comment by [aby](https://answers.ros.org/users/52503/aby/) on 2020-04-20**:
followup question has moved to #q350012.